# Como validar esta regex? AA-000

Tags: html5, regex

Estou construindo uma expressão regular para validar Matrículas de aviões.
Elas sempre são neste formato sequencial:

- 2 letras A a Z maiúsculas
- Hífen
- 3 números

Totalizando 6 caracteres.

Fiz a seguinte estrutura, mas não consigo valida-la:

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}$
```

A string de testes é:

> AB-123

Como posso validar essa string neste formato? Lembrando que:

- AB123 é inválido
- A1234 é inválido
- A-1234 é inválido
- AB-1234 é inválido

--- EDIT
Era apenas uma falha no validador, ao fazer novamente o teste, deu match na string correta.

Comment: Parece correto, como está o html/js?

Comment: Confirmando que funciona: https://regex101.com/r/cv7G4V/1

Comment: Estranho, no mesmo validador (regex101) que estava testando, não dava match em nenhuma circunstância... Agora, ao abrir novamente o validador, funcionou corretamente.

Comment: O validador apresentou como erro, mas era apenas uma instabilidade. A REGEX apresentada funciona.

Comment: ^[A-Z]{2}-\d{3}$